# Regular Expressions within a string in AWK using if/then control structure?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, awk, mawk

**PROBLEM**

I want to specifically use AWK (GAWK, MAWK, whatever) in an AWK script to sum up the values in field 9 for every record that contains "runner__.jpx" (the underscores are placeholders for two digits 0-9) in field 6 and "good" in FIELD 7.

**SAMPLE FILE**

```
Feb 14 11:33:16 ringer a[2388]: runner01.jpx good aa 3
Feb 14 11:33:32 ringer a[2388]: runner24.jpx good xx 1
Feb 14 11:33:39 ringer a[1894]: jogger02.jpx good aa 5
Feb 14 11:33:45 ringer a[2388]: runner99.jpx stop cc 1
```

**ATTEMPT**

How could I do this?  I tried using an if statement, like:

```
BEGIN {
    sum = 0
}

{
    if (($6 == "runner"[0-9][0-9]".jpx") && ($7 == "good"))
        sum += $9
}

END {
        printf sum
}
```

Is there way to do this by matching strings in fields using if statements?  Am I allowed to use regular expressions within the if statement?  What is an alternative method to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the job. Note that you do not need explicit `if`s, just use `awk`'s implicit pattern-action model

```
awk  '$6 ~ /^runner[0-9][0-9]\.jpx$/ && $7 == "good" {s += $9};
      END{print s}' input.file
```

Comment: Thanks!  Can you explain what the ~ does?  Also, I actually have several "if's" to run per line, so I have them in a file that I call with awk -f scriptname.awk input.file.  Could I do this with the implicit structure?

Comment: @JonSmith, `~` does a pattern match. And the answer to your other question is yes

Comment: Adding to @1_CR 's comment - tilde (~) does a pattern matching against a variable - in this case $6. You can do pattern matching against the entire line without it.